# Google Apps Script .getMonth isn't working if there is no available "return"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to use "get.Month" but when I run the code there's an error:

> "TypeError: exSheet.getRange (...). GetValue (...). GetMonth is not a
>   function"

When I put the "return tempSum;" outside the "if" No error and code works...

I tried putting ".setValue" instead of "return" and it didn't help.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
function CALC_EX(chosenMonth){

  switch(chosenMonth){
  case "jan":
    chosenMonth = 1;
    break;
  case "feb":
    chosenMonth = 2;
    break;
  case "mar":
    chosenMonth = 3;
    break;
  case "apr":
    chosenMonth = 4;
    break;
  case "may":
    chosenMonth = 5;
    break;
  case "jun":
    chosenMonth = 6;
    break;
  case "jul":
    chosenMonth = 7;
    break;
  case "aug":
    chosenMonth = 8;
    break;
  case "sep":
    chosenMonth = 9;
    break;
  case "oct":
    chosenMonth = 10;
    break;
  case "nov":
    chosenMonth = 11;
    break;
  case "dec":
    chosenMonth = 12;
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var exSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Expenses');
  var tempSum = 0;

  for(var i=2;i>0;i++){
    var range = exSheet.getRange(i, 5);
    var monthCell = exSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue().getMonth()+1;

    if(!range.getValue()){
      i = 0;
      return tempSum;
    }
    if(monthCell === chosenMonth){
      tempSum = tempSum + exSheet.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Move `var monthCell` below the `if` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`getMonth()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) is a Javascript function that can only be applied to a date object

> TypeError:
>   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(...).getRange(...).getValue(...).getMonth
>   is not a function

means that your cell value is not recognized correctly as a date object, you can verify it with `Logger.log(typeof exSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue());`

Verify that the cells you are iterating through are dates indeed (not strings or empty cells) and if necessary, set the data type to a date, e.g. by going from the Google Sheets UI to `Format->Number->Date`. Depending on your [Locale](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) settings, you might have to adjust your date format.

Without seeing your spreadsheet, most likely the reason for the error comes from your loop definition, as pointed out by theMaster.